# ¿Error Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estos son los siguientes pasos de como se genera el error: Tengo un input que se ingresa "json1" y doy click al boton ***ejecutar json*** se llena el datatable con 3 registros y si selecciono un registro y doy en el boton ***obtener*** me muestra en consola el registro seleccionado por el checkbox. Luego ingreso "json2" y doy click en el boton ***ejecutar json*** se llena el datatable, pero a partir del 4to registro al seleccionar el checkbox me muestra error. Pero los 3 primeros registros no muestran error.

Codigo del Error

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:116 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined
    at u.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:116)
    at u.data (jquery.dataTables.min.js:102)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (datatable_checkbox.html:94)
    at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5)
    at HTMLTableElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:5)
```

Mi debug señala este código

```
let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            function crearTabla(datos) {
                let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
                let dt = $dt.DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: false,
                    paging: true,
                    autoWidth: false,
                    bDestroy: true,
                    data: datos,
                    order: false,
                    columns: [{
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            // ACA controlamos la propiedad para des/marcar el input
                            return "<input type='checkbox'" + (full.checked ? ' checked' : '') + "/>";
                        },
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'Producto',
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'Cantidad',
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'Precio',
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    ]
                });
                let $total = $('#total');

                // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
                $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function (evt) {
                    let checked = this.checked;
                    let total = 0;
                    let data = [];

                    dt.data().each(function (info) {
                        // ACA cambiamos el valor de la propiedad
                        info.checked = checked;
                        // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
                        if (info.checked) total += info.Precio;
                        data.push(info);
                    });

                    dt.clear()
                        .rows.add(data)
                        .draw();
                    $total.val(total);
                });

                // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
                $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function () {
                let dt = $('#tbl-buys').DataTable();
                    let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
                    // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
                    info.checked = this.checked;

                    /**  NUEVO CÓDIGO */
                    /**  Verificar si todos están seleccionados */
                    var countSelected = 0
                    var countTotal = 0
                    dt.data().each(function (info) {
                        countTotal += 1;
                        if (info.checked) {
                            countSelected += 1;
                        }
                    });

                    /** Actualizamos UI según caso */
                    if (countSelected === countTotal) {
                        $('thead input').prop("checked", true);
                        $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", false);
                    } else if (countSelected === 0) {
                        $('thead input').prop("checked", false);
                        $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", false);
                    } else {
                        $('thead input').prop("checked", false);
                        $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", true);
                    }
                    /** END NUEVO CÓDIGO */
                });
            }

            // ACA suscribimos un listener
            $('#btnObtener').on('click', function () {
                let dt = $('#tbl-buys').DataTable();
                let checkeds = dt.data().toArray().filter((data) => data.checked);
                console.log(checkeds);
            });



            $("#boton").click(function () {
                var json = $("#idJson").val();
                if(json=="json1"){
                    crearTabla([{
                        "Producto": "Leche",
                        "Cantidad": 50,
                        "Precio": 3.20
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Azucar",
                        "Cantidad": 40,
                        "Precio": 2.20
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Gaseosa",
                        "Cantidad": 14,
                        "Precio": 6.50
                    }
                    ]);
                }
                if (json == "json2") {
                    crearTabla([{
                        "Producto": "Leche",
                        "Cantidad": 50,
                        "Precio": 3.20
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Azucar",
                        "Cantidad": 40,
                        "Precio": 2.20
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Gaseosa",
                        "Cantidad": 14,
                        "Precio": 6.50
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "polos",
                        "Cantidad": 2,
                        "Precio": 32.90
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "platos",
                        "Cantidad": 10,
                        "Precio": 2.00
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "tazas",
                        "Cantidad": 6,
                        "Precio": 2.50
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "mesas",
                        "Cantidad": 6,
                        "Precio": 150.00
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "televisor",
                        "Cantidad": 1,
                        "Precio": 1200.00
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "carne",
                        "Cantidad": 33,
                        "Precio": 15.50
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Menestras",
                        "Cantidad": 54,
                        "Precio": 2.30
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Paneton",
                        "Cantidad": 5,
                        "Precio": 20.50
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Arroz",
                        "Cantidad": 32,
                        "Precio": 2.50
                    },
                    {
                        "Producto": "Huevos",
                        "Cantidad": 10,
                        "Precio": 3.50
                    }
                    ]);
                }

                
            });




        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

JSON <input type="text" id="idJson">
    <button type="button" id="boton">Ejecutar Json</button>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length="2" id="tbl-buys">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <!--<label>Total</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />-->
    <br>
    <button id="btnObtener">Obtener</button>
```

Comment: El error es debido a que no coinciden el número de columnas. ¿Te aseguraste de que el json tenga las mismas propiedades?

Comment: Tiene el mismo numero de columnas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta era inicializar la tabla antes de este código.

```
var dt= $("#tabla_excel").DataTable();//Línea que soluciona el error.
let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
```